# Calling props from a container

Tags: reactjs, properties, components

I am a little confused on the idea of using props in the context I am using for my React app. In my component, I need to check if the value of a certain prop (`props.companyCode`) matches a certain string, and only then will it print out a `<p>` of what I need. Below is what I have for calling the prop in the component:

`Components/CompanyContact.jsx`

```
class CompanyContact extends React.Component {
  help() {
    if (this.props.companyInfoList.companyCode === '1234') {
      return <p>something</p>;
    }
    return <p>somethingelse</p>;
  }

  render() {
    const help = this.help();
    return (
            <div>
               {help};
            </div>
)}}

export default CompanyContact;
```

And this is what I have for the container:

`Container/InfoContainer.jsx`

```
class InfoContainer extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        companyInfoList: null,
      };
    }

    async componentWillMount() {
      const companyInfoCachedData = CachingService.getData('companyInfoList');
      if (companyInfoCachedData) {
        this.setState({ companyInfoList: companyInfoCachedData });
        return;
      }
    }

    async getCompanyInfo(accessToken) {
      try {
        const companyProfileResponse = await requestAWSGet('api/company-profile', undefined, accessToken);
        CachingService.setData('companyInfoList', companyProfileResponse);
        this.setState({ companyInfoList: companyProfileResponse });
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    }

    render() {
      return (
          <CompanyContact companyInfoList={this.state.companyInfoList} />
      );
    }
}

export default InfoContainer;
```

Nothing is returned when I run the application and I believe it's because I'm not calling the prop correctly in my component but I am unsure as to how to go about fixing it. I'm fairly new to working with props so still trying to get my bearings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are getting an error somewhere because of `this` not having `props` and `this.props.companyInfoList.companyCode` trying to access a property on a non object. `this.props.companyInfoList` is initially set to `null` so accessing a property on it will break.

A few strategies to fix the problem:

1. Default it to an empty object

```js
this.state = { 
  companyInfoList: {}, 
}
```

2. Block the rendering of the component until it has a value:

```js
if (this.state.companyInfoList) {
  return (
    <CompanyContact companyInfoList={this.state.companyInfoList} />
  );
} else {
  return null;
}
```

3. Check that the prop is an object and has the key `companyCode` on it:

```js
if (this.props.companyInfoList && 
  this.props.companyInfoList.companyCode && 
  this.props.companyInfoList.companyCode === '1234') {
```

In addition, `this` will be in the wrong context and the changes above will most likely no be enough. Try changing to an arrow function like this:

```js
help = () => {
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: I have a GET request in my container that fills it with the company information as soon as the page loads and companyInfoList's state is changed- not sure if this is what you mean?

Comment: Yes, but  it will render once before your data gets back, so it will be null at least once

Comment: If you'd like to verify, add `console.log(this.state.companyInfoList)` inside the `render` method of `InfoContainer`. If it ever shows null, this is your problem

Comment: Another piece of advice: React recommends avoiding the use of `componentWillMount`. It is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. You should substitute for `componentDidMount`.

Comment: If it does show up null, how would you recomment I fix it?

Comment: I'll list a few options in my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I'll give these a try and let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally refactor that component logic and directly use the prop value inside the render method like:

```
class CompanyContact extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { companyInfoList } = this.props;

    return companyInfoList && companyInfoList.companyCode === '1234' ? (
      <p>something</p>
    ) : (
      <p>somethingelse</p>
    )
  }
}

export default CompanyContact;
```

Comment: The reason I had the function where it is is because I have other code in the return statement since the rest of this file was mostly static content so not sure how I would be able to refactor if that changes your answer at all.

Comment: Then the answer from @Brian-Thompson should work fine